# Would adding more threads increase the performance of my program

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

In my program I have a while loop which iterates through an array list of a bunch of pictures and does a bunch  of processing on them to change how they look and  their image type and then writes them to the disk. My question is would adding multiple threads to process images or save the images speed things up, if so what would be the best way to go about it. 
    ArrayList  images = new ArrayList  ();//over 500 images
    ArrayList  paths = new ArrayList  ();
    int len = images.size();

```
for (int i =0; i < len ; i ++)
{
BufferedImage image  = process (images.get(i))//takes about a second 
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(getImagePaths().get(i)));


}
```

Comment: A sample of the code you are trying to improve will increase the odds the community can help.  :)   Based on your description it might be disk I/O in which case multiple threads may not help.  Have you tried profiling your app to determine where the performance bottlenecks are?

Comment: Assuming you process is CPU bound, I would use an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` which has the same number of threads as you have cores `Runtime.availableProcessors()` and `execute()` each write as a task inside the loop.

Comment: @GregHewgill If we keep staying away from them, then how do we learn them ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could partition your list into n blocks so that you have blocks of size of list / n, and you could then have n threads operate on these "blocks" of images. This way you have more work that can be done concurrently.

To address some things brought up, it would most likely increase I/O concurrency as well because in a single threaded run it would fault on the first miss and block, then fault again to read the 2nd image, etc... In the multi threaded way it would block for n images at a time which allows the I/O scheduler to handle more I/O at a time (which is generally a good thing). This would mean increased performance even in single core processors due to the overlapping of I/O and the availability of more threads to run on the core while the blocked for I/O threads wait.

Comment: Sure, given that there's enough RAM for that, or the problem isn't disk I/O, or it's not a single core machine, or any number of other things than can make that not efficient. The OP's question is really far too broad, lacking useful information, and his understanding of threads is obviously limited.

Comment: @BrianRoach You're right I am assuming a lot of things. Disk I/O could be an issue but multithreading would help as it would cause a lot more concurrent I/O rather than I/O miss followed by a blocking call, and repeat for every image in which case even on single core machines this would help.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it very likely would because :**

1) Your computer probably has 2 to 4 CPUs or Cores

2) Image processing typically is CPU intensive

3) Thus, the large CPU load can be split into multiple tasks that run at the same time .

**Will this always work?**

No.  If your process is i/o (internet, disk or memory) bounded (i.e. it requires 2G of memory per image, or it has to write lots of temp files, for example), you won't see a linear speed up- because the gains in CPU speed will be offset by the time doing i/o, which will slow down your program regardless of how many processors you have to share the load of image processing.  **Its like making noodles - it takes 10 minutes to boil the noodles.  Even if you have 8 different burners all going at once - the water absorbing into the noodles will still take 10 minutes, so parellelizing won't help.**

**Psuedo code :**

```
   //just a reminder ! 
   public static final int MAX_SEM=8;
   processAll()
   {
     //create a new semaphore with 4 slots.
     semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_SEM) ;
     while(! images.empty())
         if(semaphore has a slot) 
           Image img=images.pop();
           sempahore.decrement()
           Thread().run( new Runable() { public void run() {process(img);} } 
         else
           Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    process(Image i)
    {   do some work  on i 
        semaphore.increment()
    }
```

Comment: what if i say added like 40 different threads?

Comment: If you have 40 cores/processors, then do it. Just make sure the first ones have higher priority than the last ones, so your harddisk doesn't work all day and no threads get what they want.

Comment: k just tried something like that but it seems i cant really create a thread for evrey single iamge or it gets uber laggy over all i think i'll try and just do maybe 4 max

Comment: don't make more threads then necessary --- if you do that, the results will be unpredictable.  Especially if these are memory intensive .  Start with 2 - if that doubles performance, go to 4, then try 8.  I wouldn't do more then 8 until and unless you knowyour cpu, memory constraints, and threads in general.