# When I add more threads the processing time increases?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I'm doing an image processing program in parallel, I have 4 cores so when I run the program on a number of threads less than 5 there should be an improvement in time than when it's running on only 1 thread, I thought there was no improvement because the picture might be too small so there's an overhead because of the threads. So I used 8142x2175 image still there's no improvement. Could the problem be from Eclipse?

This is the main of my image processing program and I am including one of the classes, as you can see I am using Java and running it on eclipse.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final File imageFile= new File ("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Parallel\\pic8142x2175.jpg");
        BufferedImage orgImg= ImageIO.read(imageFile);

        // the destination buffered image
        BufferedImage destImg = new BufferedImage(orgImg.getWidth(), orgImg.getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // let the user enter number of thread
        System.out.println(" please enter number of threads");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nThreads=in.nextInt();

        // create the threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

        // assign each thread with its own runnable
        for (int i=0; i<nThreads;i++){

            //Runnable gsr = new GreyscaleRunnable(orgImg, i, nThreads,destImg);
            //Runnable pr = new PixelateRunnable(orgImg,20,i,nThreads,destImg);
            Runnable fr= new FlipRunnable(orgImg,i,nThreads,destImg);
              executor.execute(fr);

          }// end of for loop

        // This will make the executor accept no new threads
        // and finish all existing threads in the queue
        executor.shutdown();
        // Wait until all threads are finish


    }

}
```

FlipRunnable class

```
public class FlipRunnable implements Runnable{

    private BufferedImage img;
    private BufferedImage dest;
    private int my_rank, thread_count;

    // constructor of the class
        public FlipRunnable(BufferedImage img,int my_rank,int thread_count,BufferedImage dest) {
            this.img=img;
            this.my_rank=my_rank;
            this.thread_count=thread_count;
            this.dest=dest;
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int localRows = img.getHeight() / thread_count;
        int myFirstRow = my_rank * localRows;
        int myLastRow = (my_rank + 1) * localRows - 1;

        for (int i = myFirstRow; i <= myLastRow; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < img.getWidth(); j++){

                int px = img.getRGB(j, i);

                dest.setRGB(img.getWidth() - j - 1, i, px);


            }// end of j loop

        }// end of i loop

        String dstName = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Parallel\\funFlipped.jpg";
        File dstFile = new File(dstName);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(dest, "jpg", dstFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Output image: " + dstName);

        // the total time
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("time is:"+totalTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: first of all, each of your workers seem to overwrite destination image...

Comment: additionally, `setRGB()` is `synchronized`, so there must be lot of contention between workers. Seems you better copy image to plain array  and work there.

Comment: yes i wanted the workers to overwrite each other so i could get the output a whole image not only the part the thread was working on. sorry for my english,what im trying to say is when i didnt make the workers overwrite, my output was only a portion of the image,this way i get the whole image done

Comment: @VictorSorokin is right. Also, if you want to really speed up things using treads you should take advantage of your processor cores. To do that you should use the Fork/Join framework. If you don't you will end up with a processor switching between threads and that will slow down your operation

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736916/would-adding-more-threads-increase-the-performance-of-my-program) already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess little improvement is caused by the fact that `setRGB()` is `synchronized` method, so there's lot of contention between worker threads. You need to copy image data to array and work there.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of threads increases, there is some more effort done by OS switching contexts between threads.

Ideally, the number of threads should not be bigger than `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. This will usually return the number of CPU cores(hyperthreading will return 2 threads per core).

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to process THE SAME picture from all threads! Shure there won't be any improvement in performance, because you got bottleneck in synchronized dest.setRGB(...).

Edit: @Victor Sorokin is right in comments to question.

Comment: There **will** be improvement in working on the same data from several threads, if there is no or little contention between threads and you don't create redundant threads (i.e., number of threads not exceeding number of CPU cores). Plus, size of data must not be too small, so that thread switching kills off any performance gains. But for OP data size this isn't the case.

Comment: @Victor Sorokin, ah, ok, I see! Then, as you said, synchronized in dest.setRGB() is bottleneck.